# Usage of Regular Expressions to fetch the requirement

Tags: python, regex

In my word file contains some requirements having different numbers as "[SWS_Rte_01252] |, [SWS_Rte_01253]  |".I want to collect all these requirements as (SWS_Rte_01252, SWS_Rte_01253) I wrote one python script for this but it's not working properly, Any suggestion for this problem?

```
import re
import docx
regex = r"\\[SWS_Rte_*\\]\\ \\|"
doc = docx.Document('selection5.docx')
f = open('Res.txt',"w")
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    line = para.text
    if re.match(regex, line):
        str = line[line.index('[') : line.index(']')]
        f.write(str+'\n')
```

Comment: Please elaborate little more what are you trying to do. Read here how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is incorrect. When you want to escape special character you should use backslash `\`. You wrote `\\` - this means you are trying to escape backslash, that is, you are trying to match backslash.

Correct regex for your problem would be:

```
regex = r"\[SWS_Rte_[0-9]+\]"
```

If you want to access matched values, you should use back references, that is, modify regex, add normal brackets around stuff you want to extract:

```
regex = r"\[(SWS_Rte_[0-9]+)\]"
```

And now, after you matched regular expression, you can extract the text regex matched with `regex.group(1)`. You can read more about back-references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

**Note:**

Also, if you check regex documentation, you should see the difference and therefore use `re.search` instead `re.match`.

Documentation for `re.match`:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note
>   that this is different from a zero-length match.

Documentation for `re.search`:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your regular expression. Try this...

```
\[[A-Z]{3,}_[A-Za-z]{3,}_\d+\]\s\|
```

If you want grab something or anything like this "[SwsRt_Rhtte_552663] |". Use this..

```
\[\w+_\w+_\d+\]\s\|
```

Or if you want exactly anything like this."[SWS_Rte_*] |"

```
\[SWS_Rte_\d+\]\s\|
```